# OpenAPI Generator gradle plugin file name output

Tags: java, gradle, openapi, gradle-plugin, openapi-generator

I'm using the OpenAPI generator gradle plugin with the "jaxrs-resteasy" generator and I was wondering if there was a way to change the name of the output files. Right now it's producing ApiApi.java, ApiApiService.java, ApiException.java etc.

Is there way to configure that so the output would be MyNameApi.java and MyNameApiService.java?

Example YAML:

```
paths:
  /api/test/myname
    get:
      tags:
        - myname
      summary: Some summary
      parameters:
        - in: query
          name: firstName
          schema:
            type: string
          required: true
          description: Description holder
```

Comment: Have you figured out how to do this? I'm stuck on this too

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `tags` in the OpenAPI spec to control how the files are named. For example,

```
paths:
  /pet:
    post:
      tags:
        - pet
      summary: Add a new pet to the store
      description: ''
      operationId: addPet
```

This should generate PetApi.java and PetApiServices.java.

Comment: I have paths: /api/test/pet with the tags set to pet and it still produces ApiApi. Is this because it takes the root of the path?

Comment: I added an example YAML to the original post

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they have a PR up to add support for tags in resteasy
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/pull/6130

Edit: Actually this looks like this is support for the useTags config option in resteasy